# Groovy in Eclipse not recognizing imports

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I am attempting to run a Groovy script in Eclipse but Eclipse is seemingly ignoring all of my import statements. If I hover over the errors it tells asks me to import the appropriate class (clicking on it does nothing).

I have the required jars in my build path and class path.

Sample code, pretty standard:

```
package scripts.blah

import foo.Bar;

class FooMain {
    static main(String[] args){
        Bar bar = new Bar();
    }
}
```

Groovy:unable to resolve class Bar

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have it in the build path correctly, it should work

Comment: the jars are all listed in my run configuration -> classpath under User Entries.

Comment: What version of Groovy? What version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 Indigo with Groovy plugin for Eclipse 3.7, Groovy version is 1.7.10 I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to actually build the project. Ouch. (build automatically was turned off in Eclipse)

Comment: I have the same error "Unable to resolve class" in external libraries such as "import com.beust.jcommander.JCommander". I am using Gradle and the gradlew compileGroovy works fine from command line.

Answer (score 4):

Three possibilities:

1. The script is not in a source folder
2. The script being referred to is not in a source folder.
3. One or both scripts are in "script folders".  Script folders are folders where scripts go.  Groovy files in script folders are not sent to the compiler and therefore scripts in script folders cannot reference each other.  Check out your script folder at Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler.  Also, as of groovy-eclipse 2.6.1, there are project specific script folders, so also check in your project properties.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll try this out on Monday.

Comment: Sorry for the anticlimax, but turns out I just needed to build the project (build automatically was turned off). Not sure whether the question should be closed or how this works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem when I imported to the IDE an existing groovy project before having installed the "Groovy Development Tools" plugin.

I installed the Groovy plugin and restarted the IDE, but my project was still broken.

So I deleted the project and I imported it again, and then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Adding those to my .classpath solved the problem:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"/>
```